# quantity macro excel for inventory

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get Excel to work as a inventory scan reader. I'm having trouble with scanning because it constantly adds to col A when I scan and even if its a duplicate, I want it to be able to recognize that the item scanned is the same as the last and add to the col QTY. If any one could assist me as how to go about the code that would be great!

Pictures--It wont let me put one up but COL A is Barcode, COL B is DESCRIPTION and COL C is QTY.

Comment: See this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366823/if-detected-enter-in-column-3-then-go-to-row-1 You don't need the code for this but if you still want a code then see Tim's post in that link :)

Comment: Seems like you will want each scan to go to the same cell, and have the scanned value update an existing list, adding the barcode if it's not already there?

Answer (score 4):

Place this code in the sheet code module (right-click on the tab and select "view code").

Your list headers go in A4 (barcode) B4 (description) C4 (count).
Select cell A1 and start scanning. If it finds a match in the list it will update the count, if not then it adds a new line.  I tested just by typing in values, but should wortk the same way with a scanner as long as it's sending {enter} with each scan.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const SCAN_CELL As String = "A1"
    Const RANGE_BC As String = "A5:A500"
    Dim val, f As Range, rngCodes As Range

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range(SCAN_CELL)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    val = Trim(Target.Value)
    If Len(val) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Set rngCodes = Me.Range(RANGE_BC)

    Set f = rngCodes.Find(val, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        With f.Offset(0, 2)
            .Value = .Value + 1
        End With
    Else
        Set f = rngCodes.Cells(rngCodes.Cells.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        f.Value = val
        f.Offset(0, 1).Value = "enter description"
        f.Offset(0, 2).Value = 1
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Value = ""
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    Target.Select

End Sub
```