# Putting in a macro datestamp in this code

Tags: excel, vba

I love [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416944/quantity-macro-excel-for-inventory), but I like to add a timestamp also in this script in the next column.
I tried serveral, but they all gave a conflict.

Thank you very much!

Walter

Comment: `I tried serveral, but they all gave a conflict.` - show, please, what have you tried and what exactly wrong with your attempts

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! I recommend you take a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - and head back when you have a specific programming-related question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
If Not f Is Nothing Then
    With f.Offset(0, 2)
        .Value = .Value + 1
    End With
Else
    Set f = rngCodes.Cells(rngCodes.Cells.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    f.Value = val
    f.Offset(0, 1).Value = "enter description"
    f.Offset(0, 2).Value = 1
    f.Offset(0, 3).Value = format(now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Guy! I was probably putting more code then needed in the script.