# Attempting to Write a Loop in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to write a short loop to condense a list of received items into a concise itemized report. I scan the barcode of each item I receive and it goes into Column A, if there is a quantity of more than 1 it goes into Column B.

Here is my thought process in order to remove all duplicates of items in column A and combine their totals in B:

- Count the numbers of lines in column A, set as 'N'
- Check all cells in column B up to 'N' and set blank cells to 1
- Compare A1 to A2 thru AN, if the same combine B values and delete the line  (If A1 and A2 matched, and both B cell values are 1, then A1 remains the same, B1 now has a value of 2, and the second line gets deleted.)
- Repeat the loop for all values of A up to AN-1 compared to AN.

I know N will need to be reduced after each row deletion and I am pretty new to VBA so I always have trouble writing loops.

Any suggestions at pages to look at or simple structures I could use in my code would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Trying to turn table 1 into table 2

Table 1 ----------------------------- Table 2

```
Column A      Column B    |    Column A     Column B
11233                     |    11233         4
11233          2          |    9987          7
9987                      |    7452          1
11233                     |
9987           6          |
7452                      |
```

Comment: A pivot table wouldn't work?

Comment: Pivot table is probably an overkill. Step 2 (changing blanks to ones) will be always needed. Once done - sort by column A, then select any cell within the data range and use "Subtotal" - it will give you nice and concise view of your data.

Comment: I know how to clean the data up myself, but I am trying to set up a macro so people who don't have the experience or time to fix this everyday can one click a macro after scanning an incoming shipment and have a clean sheet of data.

Comment: Similar question with answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416944/quantity-macro-excel-for-inventory/11418475#11418475

Comment: @TimWilliams That link looks great, but I do not see a way to add more than 1 item as a time when scanning. Do you just scan the barcode and adjust the quantity manually if you are adding a quantity of more than 1?

Comment: Sorry - mis-read your question: I thought you were updating an existing list of inventory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Summator()
ActiveSheet.Columns("A:B").Sort Key1:=ActiveSheet.Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess
lastRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lastRow
    If Cells(i, 2) = "" Then Cells(i, 2) = 1
Next i
For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
        Cells(i - 1, 2) = Cells(i - 1, 2) + Cells(i, 2)
        Cells(i, 2).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems to be working great. Thanks for the help! Can I ask why you have 2 lines in 2 different 'for' loops in the code for turning the blank cells into 1?

Comment: Good question. THe answer is that I first had it only in the second loop, but the logic didn't work out, so I added a loop and never took out the second. It's there for no reason. I will edit.