# Excel tab to new line after certain amount of columns

Tags: excel, vba, row, barcode-scanner

I am wanting to set up an excel spreadsheet for data entry with a barcode scanner.
The barcode scanner sends the barcode then a tab OR an enter key depending how its programmed.

Basically I want to set up an excel sheet that we can scan 6 barcodes for each item, with the scanner tabbing to the next column each time, then when it reaches the 6th column the next tab will make it move to a new line for the next product.

I hope this makes sense. It can be done in MS word... e.g if you create a table with 6 columns and push tab 7 times it will move to the next row.
I am wanting to do this in Excel.
Thank you

Comment: People are not going to do your work for you. How have you tried to solve this problem and what part of the implementation, specifically, are you having trouble with?

Comment: Not expecting anyone to. I have tried hiding all the other columns - I cant think of any other way to restrict the number of columns in excel

Comment: Perhaps you can use VBA to accomplish this in Excel? Not to restrict the columns, but to have a TAB to the 7th column place the cursor on the first column of the next row.

Comment: Ok. How would you pick up a tab stroke in VBA?

Comment: I don't know; haven't used VBA in years. However, this is an appropriately specific question for SO. I suggest you look around for the answer (e.g. Google it) and if you still can't figure it out, then post it as a new question to SO.

Comment: @nevodj you could pick up a tab stroke with the worksheet's `SelectionChange` event (either a tab or Enter stroke would trigger this, but so would a mouse selection...).  Restrict the worksheet's `ScrollArea` to the desired columns and you should be able to do what you're describing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wrap Excel cursor to keep it within a specific range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366823/how-to-wrap-excel-cursor-to-keep-it-within-a-specific-range)

Answer (score 0):

Well... after a lot of experimenting gathering pieces of code from a lot of places and then debugging I ended up with the following VBA macro. Hope it helps! :)

1. When `TAB` or `ENTER` key is pressed the `Sub Worksheet_Change` will run.
2. It will check if it's column `F` being left...
3. If true => insert new row and select first cell `[A]n` where `n` = row number.

**VBA macro code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'Do nothing if more than one cell is changed or content deleted   
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub

    'Column F
    If Target.Column = "6" Then

        'Insert new row bellow
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Offset(1, 0).Insert

        'Select first cell of next row just inserted
        ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, 1).Select

     End If

End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
Application.OnKey "{TAB}", "Worksheet_Change" 'TAB key press
Application.OnKey "~", "Worksheet_Change" 'Keyboard ENTER press
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
Application.OnKey "{TAB}"
Application.OnKey "~"
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for effort, but `On Error Resume Next` does **NOT** stop any errors, it simply ignores them which often leads to further errors. You've also disabled and re-enabled events without doing anything in between, so those lines are unnecessary.

Comment: @DavidZemens Sure I'm not a VBA expert but I think I got the desired result. That was some code I found somewhere... Just removed those parts. :)

Comment: This is simple but it seems to work:
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

SelectedCol = ActiveCell.Column
SelectedRow = ActiveCell.Row

If SelectedCol > 7 Then
ActiveSheet.Cells(SelectedRow + 1, 1).Select
End If

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

The TAB or ENTER keys already trigger the `SelectionChange` event.

So, this might be a little tidier way of doing the same thing if you don't for some other reaason *need* to use the `Change` event instead of the `SelectionChange` event.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngLastColumn As Range

'Note: The {Tab} or {Enter} key triggers selectionChange event.'
' Modify the address of rngLastColumn as needed. It should be one column beyond
' the last column of your inputs, so if input use columns A:F, then it should
' be Range("G:G").

Set rngLastColumn = Range("G:G")
    If Not Intersect(Target, rngValidColumns.Columns(7)) Is Nothing Then
        'Insert a new row:'
        Target.EntireRow.Offset(1, 0).Insert

        'Select the first cell in the new row'
        cells(Target.Row + 1, 1).Select

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something on the issue, but if you select your six columns and transform the selection with the "create list" command, then whenever you tab to the last cell of a line you'll automatically going to the next line. Furthermore, if you're at the last line, a new one will be created. IM not sure why you need a macro for that ?