# VBA Excel Code Barcode Scanning

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have this excel spreadsheet and I'm using a barcode scanner, every time I capture something with the barcode scanner the cursor skip one column.

[image]

For example at A3 cell the info is capture so the cursor will move to C3, at C3 I capture another barcode and the cursor will move to E3 and so on; once is at G3, should go back to A4 to capture another box.

This is the code that I have.....

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo Whoa

Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(, 1).Select
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns(2)) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(, 1).Select
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns(3)) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(, 1).Select
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns(4)) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(, 1).Select
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns(5)) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(, 1).Select
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns(6)) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(, 1).Select
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns(7)) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(1, -6).Select
    End If
End If
Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

It works when I do it manually (without the scanner) but using the barcode scanner it returns to column B.

For example at G3 I capture the date with a barcode and then it moves to B4 and not to A4 so I can start scanning the second box.

I need some help to develop the right code so I can use my scanner to capture the inventory at my small warehouse

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wrap Excel cursor to keep it within a specific range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366823/how-to-wrap-excel-cursor-to-keep-it-within-a-specific-range)

Comment: Is the only time the code falls over when you scan in column G, or does it skip a column each time you scan something in?  If it's just the last column, why not explicitly tell it to go to column A and the row to be 1 more than where ever it was?  If it doesn't work on any of the columns, then that's a different story....

Something like "ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns(7)) Is Nothing Then Range("A" & Target.Row + 1).Select" as the last ElseIf line.

Comment: Normally if you look in the user manual for your barcode scanner there will be some special barcodes to scan which configure any prefix or suffix characters sent with the barcode. Use these to turn off the TAB character being sent as a suffix

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps your barcode scanner auto-inserts a tab or enter keystroke after each entry. Maybe your last line shoud be `Target.Offset(1, -7)`.Select this -7 columns instead of six could compensate for the barcode scanner tabbing to the right an extra time. Or use

```
cells(Target.row+1,1).Select
```

for the troublesome last line of code, this tells it to select the current row plus one, and definitively the column A or 1.

Comment: Please refrain from posting links to your YouTube channel.